# After Order Not sending email

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, ce-1.9.3.0

I'm new to Magento i have problem after ordering and also when i click (send email) button in order page a message come and say (The order email has been sent.) But actually nothing is happen i checked spam folder also nothing was there.

Magento ver. 1.9.3.0
[image]

Comment: at your sever SMTP is configured?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your cron is running in your

```
crontab -e
```

Keep in mind that newer Magento versions queue emails and send every 5 minutes vs the email sending instantly like in previous versions of Magento